# Timing AsyncTask onPostExecute method in two Fragments to finish at the same time in android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have two Android Fragments (Fragment A and Fragment B) both Fragment A and Fragment B executes an AsyncTask that subsequently populates a listView by calling on an API, which works fine.  However the listView is Fragment A takes longer to populate than the listView in Fragment B and I need the Fragment B listView and Fragment A listview to be in sync in how long it takes them to completed the AsyncTask onPostExecute method.  How do you suggest that I go about accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the results of the Asynctasks after onPostExecute() in variables and call a function to check whether both variable are initialized, and if yes, you can then do your operation of setting the list to the list views.

Like,

```
    List<String> fragAList,fragBList;

    public void saveFirstList(List<String> data){
        fragAList=data;
        updateLists();
    }

    public void saveSecondList(List<String> data){
        fragBList=data;
        updateLists();
    }

    public void updateLists(){
        if(fragAList!=null && fragBList!=null){
            setDataToListViews(fragAList,fragBList);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I though about this Harshith Shetty, but the above solution doesn't consider re-evaluation if the condition is not met.  Eventually fragAList and fragBList will not be null, but since fragmentA's Async Tasks takes longer fragmentB's, initially fragAList will be null and fragBList not null, which will cause the condition to fail and nothing will ever happen. I was originally thinking a custom listener.  It makes more since for fragA and fragB to listen for when the condition is met, rather than an if statement.

Comment: It doesn't matter if A completes first or B, both when done, sets the data and calls updateLists(), so if A takes time, B will complete and setData first and calling updateLists it will not set the data as ListA is not set and as soon as A completes, listA gets data and updateLists will update both the lists.